# Replace field with field from other table in SELECT query

Tags: mysql

Let us have two tables as follows:

### database.users

```
user_id | username
-------------------
    1   | some_name
    2   | another_name
    ...
```

### database.comments

```
user_id | comment
------------------
    1   | some_comment
    2   | another_comment
    ...
```

How do I run a `SELECT` which gets all the comments based on `user_id` and return the result with `user_id` replaced with `username` from **database.users**?

Comment: Do some studying on "Join" syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT u.username, c.comment
FROM users u
JOIN comments c
ON u.user_id = c.user_id
ORDER BY u.username
```

I added the "ORDER BY" clause, so you get all the comments for one user together.

Alternatively, you can add a "WHERE" clause to select a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select usr.username, cmmnt.comment
  from users usr
       left join comments cmmnt on usr.user_id = cmmt.user_id
```

If you want to filter it further based on some `user_id`, use this

```
select usr.username, cmmnt.comment
  from users usr
       left join comments cmmnt on usr.user_id = cmmt.user_id
 where usr.user_id = 1 --or whatever user_id you want to use
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12116/1

```
SELECT users.username, comments.comment
FROM users
LEFT JOIN comments
ON users.user_id = comments.user_id
```

or `INNER JOIN` if you don't need users without any comments in `comments` table:

```
SELECT users.username, comments.comment
FROM users
INNER JOIN comments
ON users.user_id = comments.user_id
```